# IIS - Use MySql on Xampp

Tags: mysql, iis

I have `xampp` on my laptop and I also just installed `IIS` for windows. I manage to configure `php` to use on my `IIS`. May I know how to configure `IIS` to use `mysql` on `xampp`? I have Google regarding the configuration but without a success result. Previously, I am using `xampp`  but now I want to change to `IIS`.

Comment: mysql is a separate service and has nothing to do with 'IIS or apache, you don't need anything

Comment: @nbk is perfectly right! It is the php code that needs to connect to mysql, not IIS! If IIS is installed on the same computer as xampp, then you can use the same connection parameters as you used in the php code under xampp.

Comment: ic, currently i need to start mysql from xampp control panel. is there a way to start without using xampp control panel

Comment: The built-inWindows service manager can take care of that

Comment: If you want to use IIS, there is no need to use apache. Except IIS as reserve proxy. Mysql can be run by cmd. It is unnecessary to use xampp executing it. PHP can deploy on IIS. You just need to make sure connectionstring is correct so that php application can connect to mysql.